# Same android SDK for Multiple Users

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk

I installed android studio on my admin account from ubuntu software center. and It's working without any issue. I have another admin account setup in my desktop PC. I can run android studio from that account as well. but the problem is I have to install android sdk manager again for that account.

Is there a way to use the same sdk manager that I have already installed on the other admin account? If so how do I set necessary permissions?

Answer (score -1):

You could do it with `setfacl`, giving permissions to all users you want.

[Linux setfacl command help and examples](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/usetfacl.htm)